# How do i deliberately say cucumber to skip rest of the steps in current scenario (java)

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

Suppose that i have Scenario like bellow:

```
Scenario outline:
Given some "<data1>"
And Given some "<data2>"
When some conditon
Then do something

Examples:
|data1 |data2 |
|11    |12    |
|21    |22    |
|31    |32    |
```

if i found data 11 and 12 then 'do something' step execute which is obvious in the next iteration if i found 22 then i don't execute 'do something' and next iteration work as first iteration. I know i can throw exception to prevent execution of rest of the steps. but there are any other way to do it like skip_this_scenario

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are trying to achieve here: do you want to fail the entire scenario outline if the scenario fails for the first data sample or do you want to make the scenario outline successful if the scenario with the first sample is successful and skip the rest of the data samples? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to "do something" when "11 and "12" are found but not when "22" is found.

To do so you could rewrite your Scenarios as follows:

```
Scenario:
  When some "11" is found
  And some "12" is found
  Then do something

Scenario:
  When some "21" is found
  And some "22" is found
  Then do not do something
```

Please note the following:
* Only use one keyword per line (Given/When/Then/And/But)
* Which keyword you use doesn't matter to the execution of Cucumber, but does matter in terms of readability of your Scenario
* Use 'Given' to set up your precondition (a known state of the system that is required to pass your test)
* Use 'When' for the action performed (of which you want to verify that it has the expected result)
* Use 'Then' to describe the expected result

So you might also need to use your "some condition" as a Given. Like this:

```
Given "some condition" is present
When "11" is found
And "12" is found
Then do something

Given "some condition" is not present
When "11" is found
And "12" is found
Then do not do something
```